# My code gives "ChatGPT-4 response is empty. Unable to generate a tweet."

Tags: twitter, bots

Not understanding. After putting the right codes in PHP I still face the error.
I have put
OPENAI API
TWITTER APIs
in their exact positions and I also put the folder of twitter-api-php which contains TwitterAPIExchange.php
but code gives this.

```
<?php

// Twitter API credentials
$twitterApiKey = '';
$twitterApiSecret = '';
$twitterAccessToken = '-';
$twitterAccessTokenSecret = '';

// OpenAI ChatGPT-4 API credentials
$openAiApiKey = '';

// Twitter API configuration
require_once('twitter-api-php/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$twitterSettings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => $twitterAccessToken,
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => $twitterAccessTokenSecret,
    'consumer_key' => $twitterApiKey,
    'consumer_secret' => $twitterApiSecret
);
$twitterApiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/';

// OpenAI ChatGPT-4 API configuration
$openAiApiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';

// Function to send a tweet using Twitter API
function sendTweet($tweetText, $scheduledTime)
{
    global $twitterSettings, $twitterApiUrl;

    // Calculate the delay in seconds until the scheduled time
    $currentTime = time();
    $scheduledTimestamp = strtotime($scheduledTime);
    $delay = max(0, $scheduledTimestamp - $currentTime);

    // Schedule the tweet using PHP sleep function
    sleep($delay);

    $postFields = array(
        'status' => $tweetText
    );
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($twitterSettings);
    $twitter->setPostfields($postFields);
    $twitter->buildOauth($twitterApiUrl . 'statuses/update.json', 'POST');
    $result = $twitter->performRequest();
    $response = json_decode($result);

    return $response;
}

// Function to generate response using ChatGPT-4
function generateChatGptResponse($message)
{
    global $openAiApiKey, $openAiApiUrl;

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $openAiApiKey
    );
    $data = array(
        'messages' => array(
            array('role' => 'system', 'content' => 'You are a helpful assistant.'),
            array('role' => 'user', 'content' => $message)
        )
    );

    $ch = curl_init($openAiApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($result);
    $reply = $response->choices[0]->message->content ?? '';

    return $reply;
}

// Example usage
$tweetText = $_POST['tweetText'];
$scheduledTime = $_POST['scheduledTime'];

// Generate a response from ChatGPT-4
$chatGptResponse = generateChatGptResponse('What should I tweet about today?');

// Check if the response is empty
if (!empty($chatGptResponse)) {
    // Send a tweet with scheduling
    $tweetResponse = sendTweet($chatGptResponse, $scheduledTime);
    if (isset($tweetResponse->id)) {
        echo 'Tweet scheduled successfully for ' . $scheduledTime . ': https://twitter.com/user/status/' . $tweetResponse->id . "\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Error scheduling tweet: ' . $tweetResponse->errors[0]->message . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo 'ChatGPT-4 response is empty. Unable to generate a tweet.' . "\n";
}
```

Please give the easiest and possible solution that may help to resolve the issue. The APIs all set to new and are in active form in the openAi and Twitter.